# RaiseCanExecuteChanged is not recognized even with the right directive

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, icommand

I'm still learning `mvvm` and coding with `c#`, but I got stuck on a problem which I don't know how to work around it. My project doesn't seem to recognize

```
RaiseCanExecuteChanged
```

even when I'm using

```
System.Windows.Input;
```

I use `MVVM Light` and in `NET4.5`

The error I keep getting is

```
`System.Windows.Input.ICommand` does not contain a definition for '`RaiseCanExecuteChanged`' and no extension method '`RaiseCanExecuteChanged`' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Windows.Input.Icommand' could be found(are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

Did anybody ran into this issue before? Thanks for your help

Here is the code I use in the viewmodel to create the command

```
public class NetworkingViewModel : ViewModelBase, INotifyPropertyChanged
{

 public NetworkingViewModel()
    {
       AddPersonCommand = new RelayCommand(AddPerson,CanAddName );
    }

 public ICommand AddPersonCommand {get; private set;}

 private void AddPerson()
    {
        *adds person to an observableCollection*
    }
 private bool CanAddName()
    {
        return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Group);   
    }

 public string Group   // the Name property
    {
        get { return _group; }
        set 
        { 
            if(value !=_group)
            {
                _group = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("Group");
                AddPersonCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: RaiseCanExecuteChanged does not exist on the interface ICommand. Can you post an example of where you are creating a command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just define your command property as relay command:

<strike>public ICommand AddPersonCommand {get; private set;}</strike>

```
public RelayCommand AddPersonCommand {get; private set;}
```

Comment: This works, however if this is an specific implementation detail in this class (and it seems it is, since the setter is private), I'd not modify the public definition of the class for this, and just cast it within the internal usage

Comment: You could have backing field of type RelayCommand and property of type ICommand, but come one, be pragmatic developer! What is the benefit of hiding relay command in this case?

Comment: I assume there was a reason (actual or future) for it to be both public and of `ICommand` type, instead of `RelayCommand`. You could change your implementation details tomorrow to other kind of `ICommand` implementer and it wouldn't break everything that uses that public property. Of course, it could turn out that this is a new library that nobody is using and it's always going to be used with a WPF `RelayCommand`... but, taking the amount of effort is near zero for both options, I always like to play on the safe side... personal choice I guess :-)

Comment: If you change public RelayCommand to something else, in worst case you would get compiler error. If you use casting of ICommand to RelayCommand, compiler will not warn you. You have actually decreased `maintanability`. Not only that, you have also decreased `readability`, because RelayCommand says, that your command does not accept any command parameter - see `RelayCommand.Execute()` method, but `ICommand.Execute(object parameter)` has parameter of type object

Comment: The key here is the publicness. Of course if you change your implementation (and use another type of `ICommand`) you have to change where you cast it, but that's ONE class to modify... if `NetworkingViewModel` is used by 400 other libraries in 200 other projects, then if you change your `RelayCommand` (for another `ICommand` implementation), then you have to change and recompile those other 400 libraries and 200 projects, and not just one class.

Comment: NetworkingViewModel is used by other 400 other libraries then yes, you should not change it. Typically ViewModel is used only by View using binding.

Comment: As I said, I play as less bets as possible when coding, since one doesn't know what the future might behold. At the same level of effort (one cast vs one type change is definitely not a lot of effort difference), I'd rather make the cast in the implementation (which I know it's safe, since the setter is private) and be wary of any changes that modify the public signature of the class.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79120/discussion-between-liero-and-jcl).

Answer (score 2):

`ICommand` doesn't have `RaiseCanExecuteChanged`, however `RelayCommand` (which you are using) does... so you could try a cast or something:

```
var myCommand = AddPersonCommand as RelayCommand;
if(myCommand != null) 
  myCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using MVVM Light you should probably make use of RelayCommands instead of ICommands, and MVVM Light's RaiseCanExecuteChanged. This is in the GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Command namespace (or perhaps the GalaSoft.MvvmLight.CommandWpf namespace - http://blog.galasoft.ch/posts/2015/01/re-enabling-the-commandmanager-feature-with-relaycommand-in-mvvm-light-v5 ). Reference that instead of System.Windows.Input .

See:
http://www.mvvmlight.net/help/NET45/html/404e779f-7c2b-875f-bf17-b8ad84bfb7ef.htm

Answer (score 0):

As @Bijington said in the comment, RaiseCanExecuteChanged doesn't exist in the ICommand. ICommand has CanExecute method, it should work.
Or you can cast AddPersonCommand to RelayCommand inside the Group property setter, or use RelayCommand from the beggining as a type of AddPersonCommand property.